# How to initialize our class while storm topology getting initialized?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I want to call the `init` method of a custom class while starting the storm topology and it should execute only once.

Comment: What do you mean by "init method"? What kind of "custom class" are you referring to (an own Spout/Bolt implementation)?

Comment: I want to execute some steps before storm topology start.

Comment: You want to execute this in the cluster I assume? What about `Spout.open()` or `Spout.activate()` ?

Comment: Spout.open() method will execute again if spout crashes.

Comment: I see. I am not aware of any other mechanism in Storm that could help... What do you exactly want to execute? Can't you do it manually -- for example submit topology in state `deactivated`, run you special code, and than activate topology?

Answer (score 0):

I would put logic on the custom class like this:

```
public class MyCustomClass() {

    private static boolean initialized = false;

    public static synchronized void init() {

        if (!initialized) {

            // your initialization logic here

            initialized = true;
        }

    }
}
```

and then call MyCustomClass.init() in each spout's open() method and each bolt's prepare() method.  The boolean flag and synchronized block will ensure that the initialization logic will be called once for each JVM.

A more elegant solution would be to use getThisWorkerTasks() and getThisTaskIndex() on the topologyContext to test to see if the current task is a specific task (e.g. the first instance of your spout) and, if so, run your initialization logic.